# Crystal Reports Total and specific totals

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I have a request to find the grand total and also the specific totals per month. I have attached a photo to illustrate what needs to be done. [Example of Request]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTHEM.png)

I have done the grand total but I have no idea to find specific totals by month.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Group the report by month. Place month totals in the group footer or header. If the value field is in the detail section, you can simply select it, hit the sigma button and elect to insert the total in all group levels. There are other ways to do this but this is the simplest.

Option 2: Insert a CrossTab with row field set to Month and value to summarize set to the column you wish to total.

There are more options but those are the most typical.